# How to properly use RabbitMQ direct exchange communication with Node.js driver?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm trying a RabbitMQ first test with Node.js connection module, I wanted to try first *direct exchange* so I got both a *server* where I'm also trying to listen to messages and a publisher script.

**Server:**

```
var amqp = require('amqp');
var connection = amqp.createConnection();

connection.on('ready', function () {

    var queue = connection.queue('mongo-ops');

    connection.exchange('badanie-exchange', {type: 'direct', durable: 'true'}, function () {
        queue.bind('badanie-exchange', '*');
        queue.subscribe(function (message) {
            console.log(message);
        })
    });
});
```

**Publisher:**

```
var amqp = require('amqp');
var connection = amqp.createConnection();

connection.on('ready', function () {

    var exchange = connection.exchange('badanie-exchange');

    exchange.publish('*', "La decima", function (err,result) {
        console.log(err,result);
    });
});
```

So, from my understanding I'm:

1. Creating `badanie-exchange` exchange which happens to be *`direct`* type.
2. Defining a queue which gets a binding to the previously defined exchange and define a routing key for it.
3. Start listening on that queue.
4. Simply connect to that queue and publish.

However when I run both scripts, nothing happens on console. What am I doing wrong?

Testing from `rabbitmqctl` I tried:

```
> $ sudo rabbitmqctl list_exchanges ⬡ 0.12.7
Listing exchanges ...
amq.direct      direct
amq.topic       topic
amq.rabbitmq.trace      topic
amq.rabbitmq.log        topic
amq.fanout      fanout
amq.headers     headers
        direct
amq.match       headers
badanie-exchange       direct
...done.
```

And

```
> $ sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues ⬡ 0.12.7
Listing queues ...
mongo-ops       0
...done.
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple minor issues with your code, for which I suggest you to read more closely the library documentation. However, there is one particular protocol issue that is preventing your code from working at all: if the exchange being declarated already exists, it must be declared with the same options as the existing exchange, otherwise a channel-error is raised and the channel is closed. From the [AMQP specification](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html):

> If the exchange exists, the server MUST check that the existing exchange has the same values for type, durable, and arguments fields. The server MUST respond with Declare-Ok if the requested exchange matches these fields, and MUST raise a channel exception if not.

Getting more specific, when you publish the message, you must declare the exchange with the same options that the server use:

```
var amqp = require('amqp');
var connection = amqp.createConnection();

connection.on('ready', function () {

    var exchange = connection.exchange('badanie-exchange', 
                                       {type: 'direct', durable: 'true'});

    exchange.publish('*', "La decima", function (err,result) {
        console.log(err,result);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's an order that you are messing with.
Try running the server.js file first then publisher.js.
If you runs publisher.js first then it will not create a working queue and nothing will display on console.